# How do I combine two functions in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I combine these two functions and alert `var price` in the `updatePrice` function? Currently I am only able to alert `price` inside the first function but I would like to call `alert(price)` inside `updatePrice` function.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{

var json = (function () {
var json = null;
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?convert=USD',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        json = data[0].price_usd;
        var price = JSON.stringify(json);
        var price = JSON.parse(price);
        alert(price);
    }
});
})(); 

function updatePrice ()
{
    var ethprice = parseFloat($(".usd-input").val());
    var ethtotal = (ethprice) / 298;
    var ethtotal = ethtotal.toFixed(3);
    if(isNaN(ethtotal)) {
    var ethtotal = "";
    }
    $(".eth-input").val(ethtotal);

    var tvcprice = parseFloat($(".usd-input").val());
    var tvctotal = (tvcprice) / 1;
    var tvctotal = tvctotal.toFixed(3);
    if(isNaN(tvctotal)) {
    var tvctotal = "";
    }
    $(".tvc-input").val(tvctotal);
}
$(document).on("change, keyup", ".usd-input", updatePrice);  

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the first function (say, `showAlert()`) as a global function then call it from updatePrice() function.

And also declare `price` variable in global scope since you want to access it from `updateFunction()` function.

```
var price;     // declare in global scope, so can be accessable from anywhere.

var showAlert = function () {
  var json = null;
  $.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum/?
     convert=USD',
     'dataType': "json",
     'success': function (data) {
      json = data[0].price_usd;
      price = JSON.stringify(json);
      price = JSON.parse(price);
      alert(price);
    }
  });
}

showAlert();
```

Now, just call *showAlert()* from inside *updatePrice()* function.

Comment: How would I compare var price with var ethtotal = (ethprice) / price; instead of var ethtotal = (ethprice) / 298;?

Comment: Declare the `price` variable in global scope. updated answer.